# scrapy xpath extract text after element is assigned

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, text, scrapy

I have such html

```
<h1 id="1"><i>2</i>sample contents</h1>
```

I know by using the following work to get only text perfectly without html

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="1"]/text()').get()  #  sample contents
response.xpath('//*[@id="1"]/text()').extract_first()  #  sample contents
```

but if I assign into a variable then want to get only the text without html after?

For example

```
header = response.xpath('//*[@id="1"]')
# the below will get text WITH html tags
header.get()
header.extract_first()
```

What I want is if i assigned to `header` and I want to get text only, how am I able to do that?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

EDIT:

By testing  Moein's answer, somehow what I get in return is `"\r\n              \r\n                            "` spacings instead

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear. Can you edit your question and put there sample input and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely updated :D

Comment: Use the code in your question, then parse it with https://pypi.org/project/html-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue your XPath address by calling `xpath` on `header` variable:

```py
header.xpath('./text()').get()
```

Comment: this gets me some empty spaces though, sryz I should have post a sample html which I did now

Comment: I've mistaken `..` with `.` now I've edited the answer and it should work fine.

Comment: I ended up founding this solution `header.xpath('self::*/text()').get()` is there a difference between this and your solution?

Comment: There are differences for sure but talking about functionality both does the same thing when you want to continue xpath from current node.